# Postgresql error on restore: [archiver (db)] could not execute query: ERROR: insert or update on table DETAIL: Key is not present in table

Tags: postgresql, restore, dump

> pg_restore: creating FK CONSTRAINT "public.fk_id_grupa_tipa"
>   pg_restore: creating FK CONSTRAINT
>   "public.fk_id_izmenio_evaluacija_iop" pg_restore: [archiver (db)]
>   Error from TOC entry 3540; 2606 218283 FK CONSTRAINT
>   fk_id_izmenio_evaluacija_iop postgres pg_restore: [archiver (db)]
>   could not execute query: ERROR:  insert or update on table
>   "evaluacija_iop" violates foreign key constraint
>   "fk_id_izmenio_evaluacija_iop" DETAIL:  Key (id_izmenio)=(1) is not
>   present in table "nastavnik".
>       Command was: ALTER TABLE ONLY public.evaluacija_iop
>       ADD CONSTRAINT fk_id_izmenio_evaluacija_iop FOREIGN KEY (id_izmenio) REFERENCES p... pg_restore: creating FK CONSTRAINT
>   "public.fk_id_izmenio_licni_cek_lista_iop" pg_restore: [archiver (db)]
>   Error from TOC entry 3528; 2606 218288 FK CONSTRAINT
>   fk_id_izmenio_licni_cek_lista_iop postgres pg_restore: [archiver (db)]
>   could not execute query: ERROR:  insert or update on table
>   "cek_lista_iop" violates foreign key constraint
>   "fk_id_izmenio_licni_cek_lista_iop" DETAIL:  Key (id_izmenio)=(1) is
>   not present in table "nastavnik".
>       Command was: ALTER TABLE ONLY public.cek_lista_iop
>       ADD CONSTRAINT fk_id_izmenio_licni_cek_lista_iop FOREIGN KEY (id_izmenio) REFERENC... pg_restore: creating FK CONSTRAINT
>   "public.fk_id_izmenio_licni_planirane_mere_iop" pg_restore: [archiver
>   (db)] Error from TOC entry 3611; 2606 218293 FK CONSTRAINT
>   fk_id_izmenio_licni_planirane_mere_iop postgres pg_restore: [archiver
>   (db)] could not execute query: ERROR:  insert or update on table
>   "planirane_mere_iop" violates foreign key constraint
>   "fk_id_izmenio_licni_planirane_mere_iop" DETAIL:  Key (id_izmenio)=(1)
>   is not present in table "nastavnik".
>       Command was: ALTER TABLE ONLY public.planirane_mere_iop
>       ADD CONSTRAINT fk_id_izmenio_licni_planirane_mere_iop FOREIGN KEY (id_izmenio... pg_restore: creating FK CONSTRAINT
>   "public.fk_id_izmenio_licni_podaci_iop" pg_restore: [archiver (db)]
>   Error from TOC entry 3566; 2606 218298 FK CONSTRAINT
>   fk_id_izmenio_licni_podaci_iop postgres pg_restore: [archiver (db)]
>   could not execute query: ERROR:  insert or update on table
>   "licni_podaci_iop" violates foreign key constraint
>   "fk_id_izmenio_licni_podaci_iop" DETAIL:  Key (id_izmenio)=(1) is not
>   present in table "nastavnik".
>       Command was: ALTER TABLE ONLY public.licni_podaci_iop
>       ADD CONSTRAINT fk_id_izmenio_licni_podaci_iop FOREIGN KEY (id_izmenio) REFERENC... pg_restore: creating FK CONSTRAINT
>   "public.fk_id_izmenio_planirane_mere_iop" pg_restore: [archiver (db)]
>   Error from TOC entry 3587; 2606 218303 FK CONSTRAINT
>   fk_id_izmenio_planirane_mere_iop postgres pg_restore: [archiver (db)]
>   could not execute query: ERROR:  insert or update on table
>   "pedagoski_profil_iop" violates foreign key constraint
>   "fk_id_izmenio_planirane_mere_iop" DETAIL:  Key (id_izmenio)=(1) is
>   not present in table "nastavnik".
>       Command was: ALTER TABLE ONLY public.pedagoski_profil_iop
>       ADD CONSTRAINT fk_id_izmenio_planirane_mere_iop FOREIGN KEY (id_izmenio) RE... pg_restore: creating FK CONSTRAINT
>   "public.fk_id_izmenio_planirane_mere_iop" pg_restore: [archiver (db)]
>   Error from TOC entry 3592; 2606 218308 FK CONSTRAINT
>   fk_id_izmenio_planirane_mere_iop postgres pg_restore: [archiver (db)]
>   could not execute query: ERROR:  insert or update on table
>   "plan_aktivnosti_iop" violates foreign key constraint
>   "fk_id_izmenio_planirane_mere_iop" DETAIL:  Key (id_izmenio)=(1) is
>   not present in table "nastavnik".
>       Command was: ALTER TABLE ONLY public.plan_aktivnosti_iop
>       ADD CONSTRAINT fk_id_izmenio_planirane_mere_iop FOREIGN KEY (id_izmenio) REF... pg_restore: creating FK CONSTRAINT
>   "public.fk_id_izmenio_saglasnost_roditelja_iop" pg_restore: [archiver
>   (db)] Error from TOC entry 3674; 2606 218313 FK CONSTRAINT
>   fk_id_izmenio_saglasnost_roditelja_iop postgres pg_restore: [archiver
>   (db)] could not execute query: ERROR:  insert or update on table
>   "saglasnost_roditelja_iop" violates foreign key constraint
>   "fk_id_izmenio_saglasnost_roditelja_iop" DETAIL:  Key (id_izmenio)=(1)
>   is not present in table "nastavnik".
>       Command was: ALTER TABLE ONLY public.saglasnost_roditelja_iop
>       ADD CONSTRAINT fk_id_izmenio_saglasnost_roditelja_iop FOREIGN KEY (id_i...

Why this is happening??